# Frame disappears with grid_propagate

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame

I was recently encountering this problem... I created some frames, and when i'm using `grid_propagate(False)` on them before I run it, the frames are empty on the window. If I run it with idle without the propagate function, there are there, even when I call the `grid_propagate` method afterwards.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
text = tk.Text(frame, bg='#000000', fg='#00cc00')


frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
text.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame.grid_propagate(0)
```

I put the specific commands behind a comment char. It only works for me, when I enter them separately in the Idle after running it.

Comment: can you please give a complete working program that illustrates the problem? The symptoms you describe could be the result of how you put `ciphertext.frame` in `ciphertext`, or `ciphertext` in the root window, and also how you create `ciphertext.frame` in the first place (ie: are you giving it an explicit size?)

Comment: I've updatet my question with a short example of the code - and I got the same error - If I'm using grid_propagate(0) before I run it with idle, I get an empty window, when I'm entering the command after I runned the script with idle, everythings behaves like it should - the frame and the text widget are still their, but the dont alter their size...
Hope somebody can help me because otherwise I'm screwed up :D

Answer (score 4):

When you call `grid_propagate(0)`, you are asking a widget to attempt to be it's requested size, ignoring whatever is inside the window. This request is honored the next time the window is drawn.

Because you don't give the frame a size, it defaults to one pixel wide by one pixel tall. Therefore, when you run the program outside of IDLE, the window is (nearly) invisible. That is the correct, expected behavior. And since the text widget is inside this 1x1 frame, it too is invisible.

The behavior you see within IDLE is a side effect of running interactively within IDLE.